# Array to string conversion error in PHP in MVC

Tags: php

ERROR: Array to string conversion in 
/application/views/main_view.php on line 11

My view   main_view.php

```
<?php echo $someval; ?>
```

my controller

```
<?php
class Main extends Controller { 
function index()
{
$example = $this->loadModel('Example_model');
    $something = $example->getSomething(1);
    $template = $this->loadView('main_view');
    $template->set('someval', $something);
    $template->render();
}   
}
?>
```

my model

```
<?php


class Example_model extends Model { 
public function getSomething($id)
{
    $id = $this->escapeString($id);
    $result = $this->query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE id="1"');
    return $result;
}
}
?>
```

I dont understand why is that a error. the return should be already in String? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What's on line 11? The `mainview.php` file you posted here only has one line.

Comment: What is $this->query doing? I guess it either returns a mySQl Result Resource or some array with key -> value pairs!? Have you tried some fetch method on $result (mysql_fetchassoc for example) or if it returns an array have you tried to access it's value $template->set('someval', $something['email']);

Answer (score 2):

The result from your query `$result` is not a string that can be echoed.

```
$result = $this->query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE id="1"');
```

I don't know what framework you're using, but you need to look into how to retrieve query results.

Comment: I am using pip, and this is just its example app

Comment: Usually query results return an array or object. You are passing that to the view and trying to echo it. You need to consult the documentation to figure out how to get a single result from the object or array.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment above. I guess the

```
$result = $this->query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE id="1"');
```

statement does not return a string. It probably returns an array or a result resource. You can print a variable with

```
var_dump($result);
```

If it is an array try

```
$template->set('someval', $something['email']);
```

If it is an result resource you probably have to fetch the data first. If it is a mysql resource it's something like

```
$arrayData = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

If it's neither you have to check the documentation of your framework.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).